# Sync Facebook user friends birthdays to my xcode application

Tags: iphone, facebook, friend

Lot of confusion understanding when I googled and studied tutorials like [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/) ,[Legacy iOS Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/legacy-ios-sdk-tutorial/#implementsso) etc.I have downloaded the FacebookSDK-3.0 as I use Xcode version of 4.2,added the sdk framework to my xcode project,then followed every step of integrating Facebook sdk in to iphone application like Facebook app id,modifying plist file,adding other linker flag etc. strictly following [this](http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-upload-photo-and-update-status.html) link.I have included the "friends_about_me,friends_birthday" permissions to my application as shown in the below screen shot:

[image]

**EDIT**

**I have already implemented the login part successfully**

But my requirement is fetching user's friends birthdays and I have a 'Facebook Sync' button for that.Now I have searched for resources meeting/similar to my requirement.But I ran in to errors implementing the answers(sample code) suggested by assisters in posts.A sample question can be glanced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323932/using-facebook-ios-sdk-to-retrieve-birthdays)

**ERROR SCREEN SHOTS:**

[image]

[image]

Where am I wrong?

Can any one please guide me,any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Look* at your own screenshot of the app settings, please:

> *“Use these settings to enter the set of permissions your app requires when displayed in App Center”*

Is that the case, is the app displayed in Facebook app center *on* facebook.com when you see this error happening? No?

> Also a billion dollar question that arose in my brain was 'Do we need to implement a user login code,does it not automatically redirect the user to login page if not already logged in'?

Of course you have to implement login into your app yourself.

I don’t know what you’ve read where, but please stick to the official documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

Comment: Sorry Mr.CBroe,I forgot to add the publish_stream,read_friendlists extended permissions and also improperly implemented the code in appDelegate implementation file,which dragged me to havoc,now I am able to access user details,friends details like name,id,birthday,picture etc.But friends birthdate is being fetched as MM/dd/yyyy,any way to get it in MM-dd-yyyy format,I mean "-" instead of "/" ,thanks :)